# How could I get the attribute(manufacturer) Url Like example.com/brands/nike in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, layout, url, manufacturer

I have a site naijafeet.com.. In this i want the products listed by attribute(manufacturer) name..If I enter `naijafeet.com/brands/nike` or puma then the items come from those attribute..Please give me some Idea,I need some help.

I fetch the brands from those attribute..and get the ids from those attribute..ans can send those data on the URL like `naijafeet.com/brands?manufacturer=81` but I don't want this..

Answer (score 4):

There have few extensions which will do this type of work:

**Free:** [Fishpig](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/attribute-splash-pages.html)

**Paid:**

- [Amasty](https://amasty.com/improved-navigation-shop-by-brands.html)
- [Aitoc](http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_shop_by_brands.html)
- [magenmarket](http://www.magenmarket.com/ma2-shop-by-manufacturers-module-free.html)

Those may be help you

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the advanced search and the url rewrite feature.

1. Make the attribute brand searchable
2. add rewrites from `/brand/<brandname>` to `/catalogsearch/advanced/result?brand=1234`